# What's wrong with this js function?

Tags: javascript

i am rather new to Javascript and i am having trouble making a function to generate a random password. The function gets called when i click a button. The empty and MD5 functions are included in a differant file.

```
function genPass(id) {
        if(!empty(id)) {
            var n = Math.ceil(Math.random()*(5*Math.random()));
            n = n.substring(0,7);
            //document.getElementById(id).value = n;
            document.write(n);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the error or problem with this function?

Comment: Any errors in the browser's console? Those will tell you what the problem is. Alternately, try stepping through your code with a debugger.

Comment: the error i keep getting is: n.substring is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The random() function returns integer type, maybe you want to make string first?

You can try it like that:

```
...
var n = Math.ceil(Math.random()*(5*Math.random())).toString();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`n` is not a string, therefore you cannot use the substring method on it. To turn into a string, use the `.toString()` method which practically all objects have:

```
var n = Math.ceil( ... ).toString();
```

It follows that `n` will have the substring method.